# Writing to Firebase Realtime Database with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've perused the forums, google, and youtube for info on writing data to a real-time database with flutter and haven't found a proper guide for even the most basic write.

That being said, in my app, I am currently trying to save the user's email to the database as a child of the user's new id. I am attempting to do this immediately after calling *.createUserWithEmailAndPassword*. This all should occur on click of a Material Button. I previously had the write inside of the then statement, but that was giving me an error.

**Code:**

```
FirebaseAuth userAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

void saveEmailInDb(String userId, String email) {
  final userRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  userRef.child(userId).child("Email").push().set(email);
}

//inside of the build widget

MaterialButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                      ),
                      color: colorPalette.chooseColor('yellow'),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(13),
                        child: Text(
                          'Register',
                          style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                              color: colorPalette.chooseColor('darkGrey'),
                              fontSize: 17),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        try {
                          UserCredential userCredential = await userAuth
                              .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                  email: tecEmail.text,
                                  password: tecPassword.text)
                              .then(
                                (value) => Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => LoadingPage(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                          saveEmailInDb(
                              userCredential.user.uid, tecEmail.text);
                        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                          if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
                            print('The password provided is too weak.');
                          } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
                            print('The account already exists for that email.');
                          }
                        } catch (e) {
                          print(e);
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

**I have instantiated firebase in the main widget:**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    GetMaterialApp(
      home: LoadingPage(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Now, I know that flutter is hooked up properly to my app because an account is created in the firebase console under authentication. However, nothing is written to the database and as there are no proper guides or official documentation, I am unsure how to proceed.

**Database Rules:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of talking about the lack of documentation for your specific use-case, I recommend instead sharing more information that you got from debugging the code. What happens when you step through the code in a debugger? Does it ever reach this line `userRef.child(userId).child("Email").push().set(email);`? Are `userId` and `email` the values you expect them to be? When you then step over that line, is anything written to the log of your app? If not, does `FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().set("Hello")` write to the database?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter of your question by the way, but can imagine this might be the reason for that happening.

Comment: I solved it sort of. Because the navigation call happened before the database write, the database write never occured. As for the documentation reference, I just wanted people to know I searched around before asking here. Anyway, it really is lacking specific examples compared to, for example, authentication: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/overview

Comment: If you solved the problem, consider posting an answer below with the specific change you made to the code above that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Moving the navigation code outside of the then statement, and below the database write, was sufficient to solve this problem. Basically, the navigation was poping the widget before the database code was called. Revised code below:

```
                MaterialButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                  ),
                  color: colorPalette.chooseColor('yellow'),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(13),
                    child: Text(
                      'Register',
                      style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                          color: colorPalette.chooseColor('darkGrey'),
                          fontSize: 17),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    try {
                      UserCredential userCredential =
                          await userAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: tecEmail.text,
                              password: tecPassword.text);
                      saveEmailInDb(userCredential.user.uid, tecEmail.text);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => LoadingPage(),
                        ),
                      );
                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
                        print('The password provided is too weak.');
                      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
                        print('The account already exists for that email.');
                      }
                    } catch (e) {
                      print(e);
                    }
                  },
                ),
```